# Split vector into balanced list (balancing sum of list elements)

Tags: r, algorithm, vector, split

Having a hard time figuring out an efficient solution to the following problem. The question is very verbose because I'm not sure if I'm making this problem harder than it can be.

Given a named vector

```
t <- c(2, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 10, 2000, 0, 20, 0, 40, 60, 10)
names(t) <- c(1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 7, 8)
```

I want to split `t` into a list of 4 elements that's balanced based on the sum of the resulting list elements while keeping the order of elements, and only splitting on non-zero elements. Expected outcome

```
L[1] <- c(2, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 10) # sum = 42
L[2] <- c(2000, 0)               # sum = 2000
L[3] <- c(20, 0, 40)             # sum = 60
L[4] <- c(60, 10)                # sum = 70
```

The **error function** I use is minimizing `sd(rowSums(L))` or `sd(sapply(L, sum))`

Trying to split the vector using something like the following doesn't quite work

```
split(t, cut(cumsum(t), 4))

# $`(-0.17,544]`
 # 1  0  0  2  0  0  3 
 # 2  0  0 30  0  0 10 

# $`(544,1.09e+03]`
# named numeric(0)

# $`(1.09e+03,1.63e+03]`
# named numeric(0)

# $`(1.63e+03,2.17e+03]`
   # 4    0    5    0    6    7    8 
# 2000    0   20    0   40   60   10
```

I wrote a function to split the list the way that I wanted (see error function above)

```
break_at <- function(val, nchunks) {
    nchunks <- nchunks - 1
    nonzero <- val[val != 0]
    all_groupings <- as.matrix(gtools::permutations(n = 2, r = length(nonzero), v = c(1, 0), repeats.allowed = TRUE))
    all_groupings <- all_groupings[rowSums(all_groupings) == nchunks, ]
    which_grouping <- which.min(
    sapply(
        1:nrow(all_groupings), 
        function(i) { 
            sd(
                sapply(
                    split(
                        nonzero, 
                        cumsum(all_groupings[i,])
                    ), 
                    sum
                )
            )
        }
    )
    )
    mark_breaks <- rep(0, length(val))
    mark_breaks[names(val) %in% which(all_groupings[which_grouping,]==1)] <- 1
    return(mark_breaks)
}
```

You can see the result is much better

```
break_at(t, 4)
# 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0

split(t, cumsum(break_at(t, 4)))

# $`0`
 # 1  0  0  2  0  0  3 
 # 2  0  0 30  0  0 10 

# $`1`
   # 4    0 
# 2000    0 

# $`2`
 # 5  0  6 
# 20  0 40 

# $`3`
 # 7  8 
# 60 10
```

It works by using `gtools::permutations(n = 2, r = length(nonzero), v = c(1, 0), repeats.allowed = TRUE)` to look at all potential splits. See how the above works for `r = 3`

```
     # [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    1
# [3,]    0    1    0
# [4,]    0    1    1
# [5,]    1    0    0
# [6,]    1    0    1
# [7,]    1    1    0
# [8,]    1    1    1
```

which I then filter, `all_groupings[rowSums(all_groupings) == nchunks, ]`. This only looks at potential splits that produce `nchunks`.

**My issue is that this works horribly with my real data because of the number of permutations involved.**

```
hard <- structure(c(2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0,
1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 6,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0,
1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0,
1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3,
0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2,
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2,
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1,
3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0,
0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2,
0, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
1, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3,
0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), .Names = c("1", "0",
"2", "3", "0", "4", "5", "6", "7", "0", "0", "0", "0", "8", "9",
"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20",
"21", "22", "23", "24", "0", "0", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29",
"30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "0",
"40", "41", "42", "43", "0", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49",
"50", "51", "52", "0", "53", "0", "54", "55", "0", "0", "0",
"56", "57", "0", "0", "58", "0", "0", "0", "59", "0", "60", "61",
"62", "63", "0", "0", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "0", "69",
"70", "0", "71", "72", "73", "0", "74", "75", "0", "0", "0",
"0", "0", "76", "77", "78", "79", "0", "0", "80", "81", "82",
"83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "0", "89", "90", "91", "0",
"92", "93", "0", "94", "95", "96", "0", "0", "0", "97", "98",
"99", "0", "0", "100", "101", "0", "102", "103", "104", "0",
"105", "106", "0", "0", "107", "108", "0", "0", "109", "110",
"111", "112", "0", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118",
"119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127",
"128", "129", "130", "131", "0", "132", "133", "134", "0", "135",
"0", "0", "136", "137", "138", "0", "139", "140", "0", "141",
"142", "143", "144", "0", "145", "0", "146", "147", "0", "0",
"148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "0", "154", "155",
"156", "157", "0", "158", "159", "0", "160", "161", "162", "163",
"164", "165", "166", "0", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171",
"172", "173", "174", "175", "176", "177", "178", "179", "180",
"181", "182", "183", "184", "185", "186", "0", "187", "188",
"189", "190", "191", "192", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
"0", "0", "0", "193", "194", "195", "196", "197", "0", "198",
"199", "200", "201", "0", "202", "203", "204", "205", "0", "206",
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "207", "208", "0", "209",
"210", "211", "212", "213", "214", "215", "0", "216", "217",
"218", "219", "220", "221", "0", "222", "223", "224", "225",
"0", "0", "226", "227", "228", "229", "230", "231", "232", "233",
"234", "235", "236", "237", "238", "239", "240", "0", "241",
"242", "243", "244", "245", "246", "247", "248", "0", "249",
"250", "251", "252", "253", "254", "0", "255", "256", "257",
"258", "259", "260", "0", "0", "261", "262", "263", "264", "0",
"265", "266", "267", "268", "269", "270", "271", "272", "273",
"274", "0", "275", "276", "277", "278", "279", "280", "281",
"282", "0", "283", "284", "285", "286", "287", "0", "0", "0",
"0", "288", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "289", "290", "291", "292",
"293", "294", "295", "296", "297", "298", "299", "300", "301",
"302", "303", "304", "305", "306", "307", "308", "309", "310",
"311", "312", "313", "314", "315", "316", "317", "318", "319",
"320", "321", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
"0", "0", "322", "323", "324", "325", "326", "327", "328", "329",
"330", "331", "332", "333", "334", "335", "336", "337", "338",
"339", "340", "341", "0", "342", "343", "344", "345", "346",
"0", "347", "0", "348", "349", "350", "351", "352", "353", "354",
"355", "356", "357", "358", "359", "360", "0", "361", "362",
"363", "0", "364", "365", "0", "366", "367", "0", "0", "0", "0",
"0", "0", "0", "368", "0", "369", "370", "0", "0", "0", "0",
"0", "0", "0", "0", "371", "0", "0", "372", "0", "0", "0", "373",
"374", "375", "376", "377", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "378", "0",
"0", "0", "0", "0", "379", "380", "0", "0", "381", "382", "383",
"384", "0", "0", "385", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "386",
"387", "388", "0", "389", "390", "391", "392", "393", "394",
"395", "396", "397", "398", "399", "400", "401", "402", "0",
"403", "404", "405", "406", "407", "408", "409"))
```

Comment: I'll offer a bounty when possible...

Comment: I've made half an attempt, something like `spleq <- function(x, n) {
  sc <- sum(x)/n;
  split(x, (cumsum(x) + floor(sc) ) %/% (sum(x) / n))
}` seems to work okay, but still has some faults.

Comment: @thelatemail it's very close...i'll play around with your idea anyways

Comment: It’s not strictly defined what do you mean by “balanced”. You probably should define an error function that you want to minimize.

Comment: @algrid you're right. I should have made this clearer. Updated my post

Comment: FYI I 'd avoid naming the vector `t` as it is already a function in R (transpose)

Comment: @Sotos it's a good point...good practice to avoid base functions, but I'll leave the example as is since it works for the purposes of describing my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if there are some analytical solutions. But if you treat it as a [integer programming problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) you could use the "SANN" heuristics implemented in `optim`. For example, consider some (sub-optimal) random split points to cut the vector `t`

```
> startpar <- sort(sample(length(t)-1, 3))
> startpar
[1] 5 6 9
> # result in a sub-optimal split
> split(t, cut(1:length(t), c(0, startpar, length(t)), labels = 1:4))
$`1`
 1  0  0  2  0 
 2  0  0 30  0 

$`2`
0 
0 

$`3`
   3    4    0 
  10 2000    0 

$`4`
 5  0  6  7  8 
20  0 40 60 10
```

The error function could be written as

```
> # from manual: A function to be minimized (or maximized)
> fn <- function(par, vec){
+   ind_vec <- cut(1:length(vec), c(0, par, length(vec)), labels = 1:4)
+   sd(unlist(lapply(split(vec, ind_vec), sum)))
+ }
> # evaluated at the starting parameters
> fn(startpar, t)
[1] 979.5625
```

The "SANN" heuristics ([Simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing)) needs a method to generate a new candidate solution. There can be more sophisticated ways to select either the functions or the starting values, but the present choices still lead to the/an [edit:] *near* optimal solution (and maybe in acceptable time?).

```
> # from manual: For the "SANN" method it specifies a function to generate a new candidate point
> gr <- function(par, vec){
+   ind <- sample(length(par), 1)
+   par[ind] <- par[ind] + sample(-1:1, 1)
+   par[ind] <- max(c(par[ind], ifelse(ind == 1, 1, par[ind - 1] + 1)))
+   par[ind] <- min(c(par[ind], ifelse(ind == 3, length(vec) - 1, par[ind + 1] - 1)))
+   par
+ }
```

Applied to the toy data

```
> optimpar <- optim(startpar, fn, gr, method = "SANN", vec = t)$par
> split(t, cut(1:length(t), c(0, optimpar, length(t)), labels = 1:4))
$`1`
 1  0  0  2 
 2  0  0 30 

$`2`
 0  0  3 
 0  0 10 

$`3`
   4 
2000 

$`4`
 0  5  0  6  7  8 
 0 20  0 40 60 10 

> fn(optimpar, t)
[1] 972.7329
>
```

Applied to the real data

```
> # use for "hard"
> startpar <- sort(sample(length(hard)-1, 3))
> optimpar <- optim(startpar, fn, gr, method = "SANN", vec = hard)
> optimpar
$par
[1] 146 293 426

$value
[1] 4.573474
...[output shortened]
```

**[Edit]** since my initial results were sub-optimal.

I'm sure you found a sufficient alternative yourself already, but for the sake of completeness: Regarding the present toy and real data examples a better choice for `gr` (I'll call it `gr2` for later reference) would have a different sampling length (e.g. dependent on the length of the data) in order to generate the new candidate which will be less dependent from the *incumbent* (the current solution). For example

```
> gr2 <- function(par, vec){
+   ind <- sample(length(par), 1)
+   l <- round(log(length(vec), 2))
+   par[ind] <- par[ind] + sample(-l:l, 1)
+   par[ind] <- max(c(par[ind], ifelse(ind == 1, 1, par[ind - 1] + 1)))
+   par[ind] <- min(c(par[ind], ifelse(ind == 3, length(vec) - 1, par[ind + 1] - 1)))
+   par
+ }
```

For the real data resulting in

```
> set.seed(1337)
> 
> startpar <- sort(sample(length(hard)-1, 3))
> opt <- optim(startpar, fn, gr2, method = "SANN", vec = hard)
> opt$value
[1] 4.5
> lapply(split(hard, cut(1:length(hard), c(0, opt$par, length(hard)), labels = 1:4)), sum)
$`1`
[1] 140

$`2`
[1] 141

$`3`
[1] 144

$`4`
[1] 150
```

And for the toy data resulting in

```
> startpar <- sort(sample(length(t)-1, 3))
> opt <- optim(startpar, fn, gr2, method = "SANN", vec = t)
> opt$value
[1] 971.4024
> split(t, cut(1:length(t), c(0, opt$par, length(t)), labels = 1:4))
$`1`
 1  0  0  2  0  0  3 
 2  0  0 30  0  0 10 

$`2`
   4 
2000 

$`3`
 0  5  0  6 
 0 20  0 40 

$`4`
 7  8 
60 10
```

Regarding the optimality for the real data (using `gr2`), I ran a short simulation of 100 optimization runs from different starting parameters: Each of those runs terminated at a value of `4.5`.

Comment: Thanks Tom - I was wondering about a simulated annealing approach, this gives me a place to start. The splits it produces isn't 100% ideal but I'll play around with it and see if I can produce the output I'm wanting.

Comment: My pleasure. Ah, right; I didn't thorougly check the results. You could change the gr function a bit to generate a more sophisticated new candidate, e.g. less dependent on the "incumbent" by widening the sampling interval to [-3,3] (par[ind] <- par[ind] + sample(-3:3, 1)) or even better: dependent on the length of vec or some other statistics. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: This is great. I'll offer a bounty when possible (14 h or so). Also, let me play around with this for a couple of days. I didn't really understand your gradient function at first, but your update helped clarify some things. I also have a question; in simulated annealing there's usually a temperature schedule that affects "re-sampling", is that in play here? And  how does it affect the gradient function if at all?

Comment: That would be nice. You can control the temperature and it's cooling scheme via control options (`temp`, `tmax` and `maxit`; please consult the `optim`-manual for details). In the present `gr`-method, neither `temp` nor `t` enter the **generation** of the new candidate. I actually never tried to access objects (e.g. control arguments) from `optim`-call within `gr` or `fn` (don't even know if this is possible). The current temp at the least influences the probability with which a *worse* new candidate is selected as new incumbent over a better current solution (in order to avoid local optima).

Answer (score 2):

By using dynamic programming you can get the true optimum in O(N^2) time. The trick is to see that minimizing the standard deviation is the same as minimizing the sum of squares of rowSums. Since the error contributions of each subvector are independent, we can reduce the search-space of 
possible splits by ignoring extensions of suboptimal splits of subvectors.

If for instance `(3, 5)` is a better split for `V[1:7]`  than `(2, 4)`, then
every split of `V` starting with `(3, 5, 8,...)` is better than every split starting with
`(2, 4, 8, ...)`.
So if we for each `1 < k < len(V)` find the best 2-group split of 'V[1:k]', 
we can find the best into 3-group split of each `V[1:k]` by only considering extensions of the optimal 2-group splits of the subvectors `V[1:k]`. In general we find the best (n+1)-group spilt by extending the optimal n-group splits.

The `balanced.split` function below takes in a vector of values and the number of splits and returns a list of subvectors. This yields the a solution with row sums `140,141,144,150` on the hard set.

```
balanced.split <- function(all.values, n.splits) {
    nonzero.idxs <- which(all.values!=0)
    values <- all.values[nonzero.idxs]
    cumsums = c(0, cumsum(values))
    error.table <- outer(cumsums, cumsums, FUN='-')**2
    # error.table[i, j] = error contribution of segment
    # values[i:(j-1)]

    # Iteratively find best i splits
    index.matrix <- array(dim=c(n.splits-1, ncol(error.table)))
    cur.best.splits <- error.table[1, ]
    for (i in 1:(n.splits-1)){
        error.sums <- cur.best.splits + error.table
        index.matrix[i, ] <- apply(error.sums, 2, which.min)
        # index.matrix[i, k] = last split of optimal (i+1)-group
        # split of values[1:k]
        cur.best.splits <- apply(error.sums, 2, min)
        # cur.best.splits[k] = minimal error function
        # of (i+1)-group split of values[1:k]
    }
    # Trace best splits
    cur.idx <- ncol(index.matrix)
    splits <- vector("numeric", n.splits-1)
    for (i in (n.splits-1):1) {
        cur.idx = index.matrix[i, cur.idx]
        splits[i] <- cur.idx
    }
    # Split values vector
    splits <- c(1, nonzero.idxs[splits], length(all.values)+1)
    chunks <- list()
    for (i in 1:n.splits)
        chunks[[i]] <- all.values[splits[i]:(splits[i+1]-1)]
    return(chunks)
}
```

Below is more detailed code for the same algorithm

```
# Matrix containing the error contribution of 
# subsegments [i:j]
.makeErrorTable <- function(values) {
    cumsums = c(0, cumsum(values))
    return(outer(cumsums, cumsums, FUN='-')**2)
}

# Backtrace the optimal split points from an index matrix
.findPath <- function(index.matrix){
    nrows <- nrow(index.matrix)
    cur.idx <- ncol(index.matrix) 
    path <- vector("numeric", nrows)
    for (i in nrows:1) {
        cur.idx = index.matrix[i, cur.idx]
        path[i] <- cur.idx
    }
    return(path)
}

.findSplits <- function(error.table, n.splits) {
    n.diffs <- nrow(error.table)
    max.val <- error.table[1, n.diffs]

    # Table used to backtrace the optimal path
    idx.table <- array(dim=c(n.splits-1, n.diffs))
    cur.best.splits <- error.table[1, ]
    for (i in 1:(n.splits-1)){
        error.sums <- cur.best.splits + error.table
        idx.table[i, ] <- apply(error.sums, 2, which.min)
        cur.best.splits <- apply(error.sums, 2, min)
    }
    return(.findPath(idx.table))
}

# Split values at given split points
.splitChunks <- function(values, splits) {
    splits <- c(1, splits, length(values)+1)
    chunks <- list()
    for (i in 1:(length(splits)-1))
        chunks[[i]] <- values[splits[i]:(splits[i+1]-1)]
    return(chunks)
}

#' Main function that splits all.values into n.splits
#' chunks, minimizing sd(sum(chunk))    
balanced.split <- function(all.values, n.splits) {
    nonzero.idxs <- which(all.values!=0)
    values <- all.values[nonzero.idxs]
    error.table <- .makeErrorTable(values)
    splits <- .findSplits(error.table, n.splits)
    full.splits <- nonzero.idxs[splits]
    return(.splitChunks(all.values, full.splits))
}
```

Comment: This looks ideal. It considers all combinations of splits (AFAIK), produces the split I'm looking for, and uses mostly vectorized operations without being too memory-greedy. I like it but I'll need to understand what you've done, and compare its performance to the SA approach.

Comment: I've added some more explanation and comments now. It considers all combinations of splits, but that might be a weakness, since it's search space is still quite big.

Comment: Hey @kuppern87: It looks like there's no way to award multiple bounties to the same question (according to Meta Stack). This is as good of an answer as simulated annealing IMO. However, because this uses vectorization, it's more memory-expensive than simulating annealing. So, when memory is limited, simulated annealing is the way to go. If memory is not limiting, this is the way to go. Hopefully stackoverflow allows multiple correct answers in the future. (I'll upvote some of your previous answers to "award" you some of the bounty, which you co-deserve).

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is "split[ting] t into a list of 4 elements that's balanced based on the sum of the resulting list elements while keeping the order of elements, and only splitting on non-zero elements.".

It's not producing your exact expected output though, but to my understanding your optimization rules were not requirements but just things you've tried to get those balanced lists. And it should be efficient :).

```
t <- c(2, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 10, 2000, 0, 20, 0, 40, 60, 10)
groups <- cut(cumsum(t),
              breaks=quantile(cumsum(t),
                              probs=seq(0, 1, 0.25)),
              include.lowest =TRUE)

lapply(unique(groups),function(x) t[groups==x])

# [[1]]
# [1]  2  0  0 30  0  0
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 10
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 2000    0   20    0
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 40 60 10
```

On your `hard` data, the results are quite well "balanced" :

```
t2 <- as.numeric(hard)
groups <- cut(cumsum(t2),
              breaks=quantile(cumsum(t2),
                              probs=seq(0, 1, 0.25)),
              include.lowest =TRUE)    

L2 <- lapply(unique(groups),function(x) t2[groups==x])
sapply(L2,sum)
# [1] 144 145 149 137
```

To compare with `138 143 144 150` using currently chosen solution.

Comment: Thanks @Moody; this is obviously very efficient, but it doesn't produce the exact split I'm looking for (and isn't very different from thelatemail's answer in comments). Since there are answers that produce the exact split I'm looking for, I'll need to consider the tradeoff in performance/results.